# limit of $\sum_{k=0}^{n} q^{(2k+1)^{3/2}}$ with $0<q<1$?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, summation, summation-method, summation-by-parts

It is easy to prove that for $0<q<1$, $\sum_{k=0}^{n} q^{(2k+1)^{3/2}}$  converges because it is always increasing and it is always smaller than the convergent series $\sum_{k=0}^{n} q^{2k+1}$ since $0<q<1$. But then how could we find the limit of the first sum?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that it is possible to "calculate" the limit? Assuming that "calculate" means "express through something we know"

Comment: yes, I got it as an exercise.

Comment: Looks interesting. Wolfram Alpha times out. Would you mind providing some contex, i.e. where does this excerise come from?